# Image in site root renders locally but not on IIS server

Tags: css, iis, asp.net-core

I have a site that is using a static image as a background.  When I run the site locally the page renders with the image (located in the project's wwwroot/images/BrickWall.jpg), but when I publish the site to a test server, the image is sent with the site and located in the correct folder on the server but the page doesn't render the image.

When I run the test server's site, enter developer tools (F12) and change the image url from

`url("/images/BrickWall.jpg");`

to

`url("/Dashboard/images/BrickWall.jpg")`

the image works.  I can also navigate directly to the image on the test server via the browser on my local machine - so the file is definitely there and accessible.

Here is the code

My razor view:

```
<body class="image-background">
    <form method="post">
      ...
    </form>
 </body>
```

My CSS

```
.image-background {
    background: url("/images/COTGBrickWall.jpg");
}
```

How can I code this in a manner so that the same code will refer to the path of the image on my local machine but also to the correct directory on the various servers it will go to?

Edit:
Here is the folder structure inside Visual Studio

[image]

Comment: Apparently the folder "/image" does not exists in the root folder of your website. I am not sure, I think you can configure an url replacement (redirecting).

Comment: Where is your css file in the wwwroot folder?

Comment: Updated with a screenshot of folder structure in Visual Studio.  But if you're referring to where the files are located in the server, it's `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard\wwwroot` and inside this directory is the CSS and Images folder.  All other CSS on the site works correctly it's just this image not displaying.  This is probably why adding `/Dashboard` before the image URL when in F12, the image displays.

Comment: modify your css to use `background: url("../images/BrickWall.jpg");`

Comment: Wow that simple.. That seems to have done the trick..  Feel free to post an answer to this and I'll be sure to check it as such.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your css to:

```
.image-background {
    background: url("../images/BrickWall.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Very simple solution!  I understand why that'd work on the server, but any idea how that still works on my local machine?  Is there some sort of CSS magic I'm not familiar with where it knows to check in the immediate directory first or something?

Comment: wwwroot is the public folder for your application, so your image needs to be there to allow users to access it. The CSS path starts in the current directory. So, we move back to wwwroot folder, then, get inside the images folder. I would need more info about your project to understand why it was working when you run it inside visual studio. But, this way I showed you is the right way. Go for it.

Comment: Thanks again.  Works perfectly!